# NERDTree Load Particular Directory Automatically

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm using gvim in windows.By default nerdtree loads C:\ drive as default.I like to change it to E:\ drive.How to achieve this?

Whenever I try to start NERDTree using :NERDTree command, I get this error `E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have the following code in my `vimrc` file

```
cd ~/documents
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
" open Nerd Tree in folder of file in active buffer
map <Leader>nt :NERDTree %:p:h<CR>
```

The `cd` command is not NerdTree specific. It just changes the working directory when Vim starts to something which for me is sensible.

Comment: How does `%:p:h` open the folder of file in active buffer?

Answer (score 6):

From the NERDTree help-file: 

`:NERDTree [<start-directory> | <bookmark>]                         *:NERDTree*
    Opens a fresh NERD tree. The root of the tree depends on the argument
    given. There are 3 cases: If no argument is given, the current directory
    will be used.  If a directory is given, that will be used. If a bookmark
    name is given, the corresponding directory will be used.  For example: >
        :NERDTree /home/marty/vim7/src
        :NERDTree foo   (foo is the name of a bookmark)`

Answer (score 1):

In my `vimrc` file,I use this `autocmd vimenter * NERDTree G:\`.The `G:\` should be set your default drive，but, it's only the NERDTree's work dir. add `cd G:\`change the vim start work dir.Just like Jeromy Anglim said that.