# Change root in NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I tried to change the NERDTree root with

```
:BookmarkToRoot <bookmark>
```

command and with `C` letter but when I close vim and open vim the root is not changed.

Do you know how to change the root forever?

Comment: see this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800840/nerdtree-load-particular-directory-automatically/5801491

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
nnoremap <leader>n :NERDTree /path/to/folder<CR>
```

I have this in my .vimrc:

```
set autochdir
let NERDTreeChDirMode=2
nnoremap <leader>n :NERDTree .<CR>
```

so that NERDTree always opens in the current folder.

With the 1st line, the working directory is always the one where the active buffer is located.

With the 2nd line, I make sure the working directory is set correctly.

With the 3rd line, I hit `<leader>n` to open NERDTree.

Comment: Thank you, you advised me many other good settings. Is it possible when I set the new root in NERDTree with `C` command that it will automatically set the `/path/to/folder` in `.vimrc` file? Or should I always edit .vimrc file manually?

Comment: Now when I start `vim`, NERDTree has root always `~` so I have to press `<leader>n` to open in the root I wish.

Comment: Greate, `NERDTreeChDirMode=2` is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

As i don't want vim to change directories automatically, i just use:

```
com! -nargs=1 -complete=dir Ncd NERDTree | cd <args> |NERDTreeCWD
```

so you can just do a ":Ncd path/you/like/" with path completion.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest what worked form me was just `:cd new-root`, close `:q` and reopen `:NERDTree`.

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed the “Working Directory:” of my GVim launcher to where I wanted the root to be.

[image]