# Using NERD tree as a Vim sidebar

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm a new user of [NERD tree](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) in Vim and am obviously not that much familiar with its features.

When I'm using `:NERDTreeToggle`, the sidebar window always opens my *home* directory, `~`. How can I change the default directory (like open a project in [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text))?

Also, how can I keep this sidebar window open in all of the new tab windows (something like the Sublime Text sidebar)? Or at least, is there another alternative to this task?

Comment: did you try to check NERDTree help file? Nerdtree has many commands, you may find what you need. Also you could create autocmd, e.g. when a buffer was loaded (or certain filetype was loaded), open NERDTree, and find the current file in the tree, (:NERDTreeFind).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817730/changing-root-in-nerdtree and the [FAQ](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/README.markdown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Vim has no concept of "project".

The closest you can get without installing clunky plugins is the "current directory": when you start Vim, the "current directory" is set to the directory where you started Vim.

In your shell, this is easy to manage:

```
    $ cd /path/to/project
    $ vim
    :pwd --> /path/to/project
```

If you use [gVim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29#Interface) or [MacVim](https://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/), the "current directory" is usually set automatically to `$HOME` if you start Vim without a file so, either you find a way to start Vim in an arbitrary directory or you use `:cd /path/to/dir` as soon as possible.

#### Without argument, the `:NERDTree*` commands open the *NERD tree* window in the "current directory".

You can use `:NERDTreeToggle /path/to/dir` to make it display the content of a specific directory.

Or you can make sure you start Vim from your project's directory and *NERD tree* will do what you want it to do.

Comment: Thank you romainl for the answer. I also find this plugin if you want to have NERDTree in every new tab:
https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs

Answer (score 4):

In your *.vimrc* file, add the following code, which will by default open Vim with a NERD tree sidebar of the current directory. So if you are in the projects directory and you type "vim" it will open Vim with a sidebar on the left showing all the files and directories in the projects folder

```
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
```

If you want toggle on and off the sidebar, just add this into your *.vimrc* file so that if you want to toggle the sidebar, just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>:

```
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```