# How can I set a default path for NERDTree in vim

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I'm using NERDTree with my MACVIM. How can I specify in my .vimrc that I want NERDTree to show the following path on startup :

```
/Users/<me>/dev
```

Comment: apparently, a simple `cd /Users/<me>/dev` in the .vimrc does the job... Is that the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Do you have trying that: ? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817730/changing-root-in-nerdtree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817730/changing-root-in-nerdtree)

Comment: How about `:NERDTree /Users/<me>/dev<CR>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a simple `cd /Users/<me>/dev` in the .vimrc