# NERDTree doesn't open a node

Tags: macos, vim, plugins, macvim, nerdtree

Currently I'm using `MacVim`, and `NERDTree` is one of the plugins I use in my configuration. Say I have this hierarchy of directories:

```
dir1/file1
dir2/file2
dir3/some/more/directories/file3, file4, file5
```

If I run `cd dir3/some/more/directories/` and `mvim file3`, and suddendly I open `NERDTree`, in order to see and open `file4` and `file5` I have to move `NERDTree` back to `dir3` and, after that, I have to return to `directories/`. There is a way to evade this behavor?

Comment: Try with `:NERDTreeCWD`.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス I've tried that. It doesn't make me change directory, the only thing it seems to work is what I have written.

Comment: Have you tried this **[solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5818335/4392605)** ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス It doesn't work for my problem.